# how to generate a control flow graph from Python jupyter notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-lab, control-flow-graph

Is there an automated way to generate a control flow graph from Python jupyter lab notebook? I see some other solutions like py2cfg and staticfg but they require a *.py file.

I suppose I could copy and paste into a *.py but figured it's worth asking. Thank you.

Comment: You may be interested in https://github.com/krassowski/nbpipeline (my own solution, it requires a bit of tinkering to get it to work but as far as I know it it the only tool which enables automatic generation) or Elyra pipelines (require manual specification).

Comment: If you need help wit this one please let me know.